# unable to login into remote machine through tcl script due to password prompt

Tags: shell, ssh, tcl

I am facing unable to access login into the remote server using ssh in the `tcl` script which is getting stuck at the password prompt

```
exec ssh foo@barRemote "ls /tmp\;exit\;"
```

while I am able to log using shell script from bash and encounter no password prompt (we have already setup up public key and private key)

Comment: FWIW, `exec ssh foo@barRemote ls /tmp` is equivalent.

Comment: Manually, try `ssh -v foo@remote` to verify that the remote machine allows public key authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried against a server where I know I've set up the key-based access correctly and it worked. That — plus the fact that it works for you at the terminal — means I suspect that the problem is that your script is running in a context that hasn't been granted access to the key (e.g., from cron). In the simplest case (which is definitely *not* inside cron!) the fix is to run the overall script within `ssh-agent`:

```
ssh-agent tclsh yourscript.tcl
```

(That sets an environment variable that lets the inferior `ssh` use the key it needs.)